# Calculating a rolling average over an entire dataframe

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I am being a moron but I just can't figure it out. Sorry in advance for the dummy question.

I'm trying to create a new dataframe that is the rolling 3-period mean of an existing dataframe

The existing dataframe, df, looks likes this:

```
            A    B    C
2019-12-31  100  200  300
2020-01-31  200  400  600
2020-02-29  400  800  1200
```

When I write:

```
df_1 = df.rolling(window = 3, min_periods = 3).mean()
```

It returns the following error message:

'Rolling' object has no attribute 'rolling'

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the type of df? (`print(type(df))`)

Comment: Actually, I discovered I really was being a moron. I was running the rolling() in a different part of the Jupyter notebook. When I moved it nearer the data it worked!. sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for replying!